# Online/Offline Viewing Workflow iOS App

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an iOS app that has a few pages. I am fetching full App (for all the page) JSON data upon login, then storing them into CoreData, so that the data is immediately available for offline viewing. (Read only)

My Question is how to implement the online/offline viewing scenarios.

1. A user should be able to do CRUD operations to the Server API when online. As well as CoreData and UI need to be updated at that time
2. A user should only be able to Read data when offline.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the main thread and the fetch results controller to (only) read the data and update the UI. Use a concurrent thread to update the API (or sync client data-store) whenever the network is reachable.

Comment: There is no way to know, whether you have a connection to the server (aka "being online"). Even if there is a safe way to test it, in the very next moment a thermonuclear weapon can explode at your server and then it is gone. Simply try to execute the operation and check, whether it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [THIS Git project](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift.git) to do this:

```
 extension UIViewController { 
     /** 
      Check network availability with Ashley Mills' Reachability. 
      */ 
     func doReachability(_ reachability: Reachability,_ completion: @escaping (_ connected: Bool?) -> Void)  { 
         reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in  
             completion(true) 
         } 
         reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in  
             completion(false) 
         } 
         do{ 
             try reachability.startNotifier() 
         }catch{ 
             print("could not start reachability notifier") 
         } 
     }
```

Then in the view you need to do this:

```
let reachability = Reachability()! 

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
         super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
         doReachability(reachability) { (connected) in 
             if connected == false { 
                 print("No Connection! Your device isn't connected to the network." /* DO ANY WORK HERE */ 
             { else {/*Connected work here*/}
        }) 
    } 
}
```